# How to send value of one component form input to another component in Angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I want to display the username entered in the login component to the home component through routing after clicking on the button.

**logincomponent.html**

```
  <form>
     <label for="">User Name</label>
     <input type="text" #uname><br><br>
     <label for="">Password</label>
     <input type="password"><br><br>
     <button (click)="login(uname.value)">Login</button>
  </form>
```

**logincomponent.tc**

```
   constructor(private router:Router) { }
     ngOnInit() {
     }

     login(uname:string){
       this.router.navigate(['home']);
       //alert(uname);
       //  console.log(uname);
    }
```

**homecomponent.html**

```
    <h3>Welcome to {{ userName }}</h3>
```

**homecomponent.ts:**

```
    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) { }
     userName : string;
     ngOnInit() {
       this.userName = this.route.snapshot.params.uname;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relation between both components you’re using, you can define a service which contain username and assign your username to that field in LoginComponent, then get it back on ngOnInit of your HomeComponent, this should  do what you expect.